# Datagrid style help XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, controltemplate, blend

I just learned how to create SampleData and place them into a Datagrid using Blend. I havent found good tutorials on styling Datagrid without using WPFToolkit or Infragistics. I have extracted the template and styles from it, but I'm not sure where to even start hacking into the style.

I would like to create a Datagrid similar to this image http://blogs.infragistics.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/kiril_5F00_matev/XamDataGridFilteringSlider.jpg

Also, I would want to have it so when someone selects a row an arrow will show up for that row. Are there any good tutorials or codes you can share? A break down of the parts that make up the Datagrid control would surely help me understand better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always loved [Jaime Rodriguez's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx) for most basic DataGrid styling

And if you're looking to overwrite the template entirely, you can find [the default template on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248.aspx)

Comment: Hey Thanks! I don't know how I missed this on google search. I'll check it out!